# Get arguments from list passed to function inside a function

Tags: r

I want to apply a function over a list of models.  I would like to organize the output by having the name of the model precede its output.  Here is a (very) simplified example using `match.call()` based on [this r-help thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/get-arguments-passed-to-function-inside-a-function-td3783894.html):

```
x   <- rnorm(10)
y   <- rnorm(10)
mod <- lm(y~x)
fun <- function(model){
 name <- as.character(match.call()[[2]])
 p    <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,4]
 return(paste(name, "; p =", p))
}
```

If I feed it a single model, it works fine:

```
> fun(model=mod)
[1] "mod ; p = 0.901618595026321"
```

But if I apply it to a list, named or not, it does not work:

```
> lapply(list(mod, mod), fun)
[[1]]
[1] "[[ ; p = 0.901618595026321" "X ; p = 0.901618595026321" 
[3] "i ; p = 0.901618595026321" 

[[2]]
[1] "[[ ; p = 0.901618595026321" "X ; p = 0.901618595026321" 
[3] "i ; p = 0.901618595026321" 

> lapply(list(modA=mod, modB=mod), fun)
$modA
[1] "[[ ; p = 0.901618595026321" "X ; p = 0.901618595026321" 
[3] "i ; p = 0.901618595026321" 

$modB
[1] "[[ ; p = 0.901618595026321" "X ; p = 0.901618595026321" 
[3] "i ; p = 0.901618595026321"
```

For clarity, what I want is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "modA ; p = 0.901618595026321"
[[2]]
[1] "modB ; p = 0.901618595026321"
```

Comment: Step through the `lapply` code after doing `debug(fun)` - you will see that `match.call()[[2]]` gives `X[[i]]` regardless - the names aren't passed through or known to the internals of the function.

Comment: @thelatemail, that's true. I'm trying to figure out how to get the names to be passed through & known to the internals of the function.

Comment: I think Landau's answer below is the most reasonable method.

Comment: @thelatemail, yes I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use `lapply` over the names of the list instead?

```
fun2 = function(models, name){
  model <- models[[name]]
  p <- summary(model)$coefficients[2,4]
  return(paste(name, "; p =", p))
}
mods = list(modA = mod, modB = mod)
lapply(names(mods), fun2, models = mods)
# [[1]]
# [1] "modA ; p = 0.828746440943558"

# [[2]]
# [1] "modB ; p = 0.828746440943558"
```

Comment: This is very clever. With a bit of shoehorning, this worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
mLst <- list(modA=mod, mobB=mod)
p <- lapply(mLst, function(m) summary(m)$coefficients[2,4])
as.list(mapply(function(n,p) paste(n,p, sep=" ; "), names(mLst), p))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work given what I'm actually doing. The example is just to give people something to work with. Thank you for your help, nonetheless.

Comment: Can you modify your question or give reasons as to why it wont work?

Comment: I'm afraid not without pasting in a lot of code. The function I'm trying to write has a lot going on inside, most of which isn't relevant to my central question. There may be some way to adapt this, but it's beyond my abilities. I do appreciate your efforts.